# Rsyslog Variable in Template Name

Tags: linux, rsyslog

Does anyone know if I can use a variable as a template name? I want something like this:

```
set $.templateName = "\"json_lines_default\"";

if $programname contains "app_log" then {
    set $.templateName = "\"msg_only\"";
}


action(
  type="omfwd"
  template= templateName
  Target="10.114.22.111"
  Port="5000"
  Protocol="tcp"
)
```

I am using Rsyslog 8.